# Opening multiple web links causes pages to 404 or timeout

Tags: internet, browser, tcpip, http-status-code-404

I'm using chrome/firefox on windows 7, on fiber, at the office. When browsing the web and opening multiple concurrent pages some of them will 404, timeout, or hang. This doesn't seem to happen to anyone else on my switch. I asked IT and they thought it may be a tcpip-conncurrent-connection issue but that isn't supposed to occur on Windows 7.

Any idea what would cause this to occur?

Comment: Technically, it is concurrent- **incomplete** -connection.  Basically, you can only make 10 **incomplete** connections at one time.  If they haven't connected yet, then others are put into a queue.  But the number of **complete** or connected connections is a different number. . .

Comment: That's crazy considering the number of http requests a single page can make. Especially one with advertisements.

Comment: I don't think you understand what an incomplete connection is or how TCPIP works.  An http request != TCP connection. Theoretically, you can make as many requests over a TCP connection as you want. . .

Comment: So how do I increase the number of incomplete-connections limit.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/2afc725f-44fd-4ae1-9eb8-f0c3a0f552bc/  The limit was removed in Windows 7.

Comment: If it's not incomplete connections and not complete connections, What would cause my browsers to hang and timeout like this.

Comment: No idea. That's the beauty of the Internet.  Your network traffic will touch 100 devices before it hits the webpage :) Each device could screw with your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

multiple? 1000, 100, 10, 2?

windows used to have a low limit for concurrent connections. If you do a search in google you'll find many tips about this issue; for example:

http://www.speedguide.net/articles/firefox-ie-browser-tweaks-2448

Comment: Excellent have you seen any similar tweaks to Chrome?

Comment: Multiple meaning 2-5